# `\leftrightarrow` in `\xymatrix`

Tags: arrows

I have the following diagram and I would like also to have `\leftrightarrow` between the sets on the same level, like the red arrow that I have drawn in the picture. I cannot seem to find any code for this kind of arrow. Do I have to use something else besides `\xymatrix`?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{
\{\text{variet\u a\c ti afine}\}\ar[d]&  \{\text{inele finit generate,   f\u ar\u a nilpoten\c ti, peste un corp algebric \^inchis }K\}\ar[d]\\
\{\text{scheme afine}\}&\{\text{inele comutative cu unitate\}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\ar@{<->}[r]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\ar` command can be followed by `@{<arrow spec>}` for changing the arrow type; in your case, you can use

```
\ar@{<->}[r]
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  \{\text{variet\u a\c ti afine}\}\ar[d] \ar@{<->}[r] &
    \{\text{inele finit generate,   f\u ar\u a nilpoten\c ti, peste un corp algebric \^inchis }K\}\ar[d]\\
  \{\text{scheme afine}\}& \{\text{inele comutative cu unitate\}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]